# What is ResolveAssemblyReference.cache?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, resolveassemblyreference

What is the file `ResolveAssemblyReference.cache` used for and does it need to be checked in?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It is a file produced by the ResolveAssemblyReference build target.  MSDN has this to say about it:

> Visual Studio attempts to execute
>   targets with certain names when it
>   loads a project. These targets include
>   Compile, ResolveAssemblyReferences,
>   ResolveCOMReferences,
>   GetFrameworkPaths, and
>   CopyRunEnvironmentFiles. Visual Studio
>   runs these targets so that the
>   compiler can be initialized to provide
>   IntelliSense, the debugger can be
>   initialized, and references displayed
>   in Solution Explorer can be resolved.
>   If these targets are not present, the
>   project will load and build correctly
>   but the design-time experience in
>   Visual Studio will not be fully
>   functional.

If I interpret this correctly, I'd say that the file is used to help the IDE provide proper IntelliSense and assembly reference status in the References node.  It is a fairly expensive operation since there are potentially a lot of assemblies that can be referenced.  So instead of doing this repeatedly, the .cache file can help make this quick.  Deleting it isn't an issue, it will be recreated when the project is reloaded.

Comment: Ah, great.  It's not checked in, so I knew it's automatically generated.  I wanted to make sure it didn't provide something useful in a (semi-)production environment, like improving the usefulness of stack traces (*.pdb files), but it sounds like it doesn't.  Cool.

Comment: I guess this file can safely be ignored (not cheked in) in your source control system.

Answer (score 4):

It is not needed to be checked in, so to exclude it from git, add the `obj` folder, for "obj\debug", to be excluded during git processes which will exclude it properly.

Comment: Was this comment attempting to answer a question? It doesn't seem to make any sense.