# Why is Visual Studio so slow at moving files around in a large project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to reorganize a large project into separate folders, and any time I try to move some files, there is an approx 10 second delay per file. <s>The project is source controlled in TFS</s> (I removed the bindings and it's still slow).

Why is VS is so slow at moving files around in a project? Is there anything I can do to move these files faster?

Comment: Try using file monitoring of Process Monitor to see which files are being accessed.  If you see a lot of activity reading some silly VS files for indexing (e.g. .opt) or weird metadata, you might just have to remove them.

Comment: Process Monitor showed the biggest hit as ResolveAssemblyReference.cache with ~160 writes while moving 60 files. Maybe I'll try disabling Intellisense.

Comment: If that file is big, try deleting it.  It could have gotten fragmented.

Comment: I think [ResolveAssemblyReference.cache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618950/what-is-resolveassemblyreference-cache) is a temporary file. I only see it in Process Monitor, I don't see if I just search my solution folders.